# How to add a specefied number of characters in django form

Tags: python, django

so I am trying to build a django form for accepting orders for my ecommerce website. I want the user to enter their zip code, but it should be of only 6 characters, not more, not less. How can I achieve this?

Here is my form so far:

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=6)
```

The `max_length` attribute allows the user to enter less than 6 characters, which is not what I want. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify a [**`min_length=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.min_length):

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=6, min_length=6)
```